# C++ do while loop

Tags: c++

I tried to make a program to get the amount after certain days of investment at some rate.my try was the below program it didnt gave any errors but also it didnt gave the result.please help.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cmath>
     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {
     float a;
     float p;
     float r ;
     int days;
     int day;
     cout << "Enter the a principal amount"<<endl;
     cin >>p;
     cout <<"Enter the rate "<<endl;
     cin >>r;

     cout << "Enter number of days"<<endl;
     cin>> days;
     do(){
        a= p* pow(1+r,day);
      cout << day << "-------"<<a<<endl;
     day++;
       }
     while (day <=days);

      }`
```

Comment: this is just do{ } while(condition); not do(){}while();

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we are not a code-debugging service.

Comment: Apart from the correct answers about your `do`-syntax being incorrect, why not use a `for`-loop? In addition you can make this more efficient by avoiding the `pow`.

Answer (score 3):

1.You haven't initialized 'day' variable.

----> day=1;

2.The syntax of do while is wrong.

```
do{

}while(condition);
```